# Xamarin forms invoking C# from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin.forms, webview

I am trying to add Apple Pay/Google Pay to my existing app. Our payment processor only offers a hosted payment option. I would like to host their iframe in a WebView - but will need to have a callback into my app from JavaScript. I found this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/
but the Android version does not work. The iOS version works perfectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of the problem

Comment: The sample is has an input field and a button rendered in html. The button is supposed to call a C# function that displays an alert box with whatever you type in the input field. On iOS, it works exactly as expected. On Android, nothing happens when you click the button.

Comment: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add to question all relevant code. (2) "Nothing happens": Set a breakpoint in the code that runs on button click. Verify that the breakpoint is reached on iOS. Is that breakpoint reached on Android? (3) Are you testing on an emulator? If so, attach an Android phone to your PC. Run from Visual Studio. See whether the breakpoint is reached there.